# Wiring Multiple MPU 6050 to Micro/Lenardo

Tags: i2c, arduino-leonardo, arduino-micro, mpu6050, atmega32u4

*disclaimer I am new at hardware/circuits*

I am currently trying to connect two MPU-6050 to a single Micro board.
In addition, there are 5 additional buttons to be connected.

I am under the impression to connect multiple devices to the I2C bus, there must be unique addresses. I read there was a way to make unique addresses (https://playground.arduino.cc/Main/MPU-6050/#multiple).

However I am not sure of the wiring or if the voltage/resistors/anything is supposed to be located.

I have a sketch of what it may look like.
[image]

Can anyone help me verify that this is the proper configuration? Or what a proper configuration would look like?

Answer (score 1):

Buttons are just buttons. You can have them "active high" with pulldown resistors as you have there (10K is fine. The actual value doesn't really matter, just don't have it too low or excess current will be drawn), or "active low" without resistors and connecting to ground when pushed instead of VCC and use INPUT_PULLUP. The choice is yours. There's no real benefit in this situation to either way of doing it.

The critical part is your AD0 connection. Whether you connect one to ground and leave the other unconnected, or connect one to VCC and leave the other unconnected, depends entirely on the design of the breakout board. It should have a resistor on the AD0 pin internally that either connects it to GND or to VCC. If it connects to GND then you need to link that pin to VCC to override it. If it connects it to VCC (or more likely 3.3V) internally then you need to connect it to GND to override it.

To find out which you will have to either consult the documentation or schematic for the board or measure the voltage at the AD0 pin. If it measures 0V (within a few mV) then it connects to ground and you will have to connect it to VCC to override it. If it measures more (probably nearer 3.3V) then connect it to ground to override it.

Because those chips are 3.3V and the board contains a 3.3V regulator (if your boards are the same as you picture in your wiring diagram) the chances are that the AD0 is pulled up to 3.3V so you just need to connect one to ground.

So it looks to me like your wiring diagram is most likely suitable and correct, pending confirmation of the pullup/pulldown in the AD0 pin.